# adb - How to reinstall an app, without retaining the data?

Tags: android, apk, adb, command-prompt

```
adb install foo.apk
```

When using this command, if the apk exists, I should get the error *Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]*

```
 adb install -r myapp-release.apk
```

In this case,the existing apk will be replaced, by retaining old data
according to the docs,

> '-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data

Now how do I reinstall the app, but all previous data should be erased?

**EDIT**

I know we can do this

```
adb uninstall com.package.foo & adb install foo.apk
```

I just wanted to know if there is a command or something in adb itself.

Comment: hi , i try : adb install -r myapp-release.apk But I cant Update app , i want update the app without creare data , do you know solotion ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Before the installation **clean the data** like this:

```
adb shell pm clear com.package.foo
```

then you can install normally using:

```
adb install foo.apk
```

or just run through your IDE

Answer (score 13):

Try `adb uninstall yourpackage.whatever.com`, then install again. Or select Clear data on the phone for that application.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, whenever I ran `adb install something.apk` `adb` outputted `Performing Streamed Install` and then `Success` but the APK wouldn't get installed on my phone. After I ran `adb uninstall bundle.id.something`, `adb install` started working.

Answer (score 12):

```
adb install [-l] [-t] [-r] [-s] <file> - push this package file to the 
   device and install it
   ('-t' uses for install debug apk)
   ('-l' means forward-lock the app)
   ('-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data)
   ('-s' means install on SD card instead of internal storage)

adb uninstall [-k] <package> - remove this app package from the device
   ('-k' means keep the data and cache directories)
```

If you want to install `debug.apk` file without `clear the data`:

```
adb install -t -r D:/debug.apk
```

If you want to install `debug.apk` file with `clear the data`:

```
adb shell pm clear com.package.app
adb install -t D:/debug.apk
```

And to start the app on Device via adb command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.app/com.package.app.activity.MainActivity
```

Comment: adb install -t -r D:/debug.apk   work for me, my phone is pixel, thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

It's `adb uninstall com.package.foo && adb install foo.apk`, however the uninstall won't work if the app is a system app, which can't be uninstalled. There's the command `adb shell pm clear packageName` to clear a certain app's data, however it may require root. To reinstall the apk as usual `adb install -r app.apk`

Answer (score 4):

No. There is no (documented) way to do that with the `adb install` command. Instead, you should do this:

```
adb uninstall com.your.package
adb install foo.apk
```

Comment: actually it should be 
`adb uninstall com.foo.foo`
I just wanted to know if there was a some command in adb itself