# Android apk install: How to clear files from old version?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

When I install a new version of my .apk, this overwrites the old version without deleting it: In the new version, I deleted some files (libraries generated with NDK) --- but on the device, the old files are still there.

How can I ensure that whenever a new version is installed, all old files will be deleted before the installation?

**Edit/Clarification:** This question asks for a solution for existing users of my application.  I know that I can clean up the application myself by uninstalling it before installing the new version.  But other users will not do this --- keeping the old files on their devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adb - How to reinstall an app, without retaining the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483720/adb-how-to-reinstall-an-app-without-retaining-the-data)

Comment: @EvZ --- thanks a lot for the link.  I clarified my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just before re-installing your application

```
adb install -r myapp-release.apk
```

You have 2 options:
First one is to uninstall your application before installing the new version.

```
adb uninstall com.your.package
```

Second one is to clear application data before installing the new version.

```
adb shell pm clear com.your.package
```

Comment: Thanks for your help --- I now clarified my question: I need a solution for the standard "one-click" installation process.

Comment: As a "one-click" solution you can write sh or bat with the commands and use it to install the APK in your way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually on your android phone by going to Settings > Applications > [your_app].
Then you can "clear saved data" or something like this.