# Android: app shut down in debug process

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug, android-developer-api

This is an issue with Android Studio settings or something else I don't know? When I debug the app and at some debug breakpoint(Breakpoint is not fixed for every shut down it varies every time) it shut downs the app and never shows in debugging choose process dialog. To get it again in the debug process I need to run the app again.

Why this all is happening, Is there any Android Studio settings required to stop this all happen?

My Android Studio version is 2.2.1. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517480/android-studio-debug-application-on-device

Comment: @Mainkandan Yes I checked these all points. My issue happens randomly when I do adb -kill server, uninstall and installing app again, switch off and on phone  it resolve issue for some time but it happens again.

Comment: adb install -r applicationname.apk -- the -r option says to replace the existing app. If you don't use -r, you must increase the version in your manifest in order to install over the top of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

adb install -r applicationname.apk -- the -r option says to replace the existing app. If you don't use -r, you must increase the version in your manifest in order to install over the top of the previous one.

(or)

[adb - How to reinstall an app, without retaining the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483720/adb-how-to-reinstall-an-app-without-retaining-the-data)

Comment: My question is not about reinstalling an app. I asked, app shutdowns at some debug breakpoints why?

Comment: If you using step-over ?

Comment: Either I use step-over or continuous debug it should never shut down app.

Comment: Make sure your java files don't have any break point and Restart the device every thing should be normal.

Comment: A first thing without putting any breakpoint in java class how can I debug my code? Next thing restarting the device or reinstalling app are not the permanent solution. I am looking for why it happens, Is there any issue with android studio settings, that I not done or something else?